# how to develop an app for a website which don't provide API

Tags: web, asp.net-web-api

I want to develop an iphone app for a website which don't provide api.I hava  a solution like this:

1. I used opensource TFHpple lib Analysis website to get request parameters in post method and the results in get method
2. Custom made an api for the website
3. Call the API

But by this way, I found it's a little Complex and Unreliable.

Could someone have some other way to implement this? In my opinion, if I can develop a JSON API for this website. But I have not enough experience to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is pretty much the way to do it.

Personally I just used search and regular expressions but `TFHpple` seems like a good way to go.

In my case I used regular expressions that I updated from my server to the app so if and when the web site changed I would just change them on the server and the app would be able to parse the changed site without having to update the app.